# Detached DOM tree memory leak

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I've discovered that my application has a memory leak, and I think it is caused by detached DOM trees. I haven't really tried to fix a memory leak before, so I have some questions.

I've taken a heap snapshot of my app and via the class filter searched for detached:[image]

1. Some of the detached trees have 0 retained size, but when I open them, I can see elements that DO have some retained size. Should i worry about these?

I have now taken 5 snapshots over some time. I have noticed some detached trees occur in all of them but with an increased retained size every snapshot, and in the latter snapshots, I get more results from the "detached" class filter. This has led me to believe that I have found the leak. I've read that nodes highlighted with yellow have direct javascript references to them, while those highlighted with red don't, but are a part of a yellow node's tree.

2. I haven't found any occurrences of yellow nodes, but I have a huge of amount of reds from my heap snapshots. How come, and how do I deal with them?

I have noticed that a lot of the nodes highlighted red refer to `HTMLImageElements` from HTML code like this (I have pretty much the exact same code in 3 different HTML files):

```
    <div class="O2-copd-flex">
      <div class="O2">
        <p>
          <img draggable="false" [matTooltip]="translations?.Tooltip.O2" (click)="toggleO2(bed)" [src]="bed.additional_O2 ? medO2 : noO2">
        </p>
        ...
```

And I also have many `Text` nodes highlighted red. I inspected one of them and it said that the node's next sibling is an `img`, it's parent is a `p`, whose parent is a `div` with the class `O2`. In other words, that text should be placed between the `<p>` start tag and the `<img>` start tag in the HTML above, but as you can see, there's no text. This could be caused by the `matToolTip` though, but I'm not sure.

3. Do you have any idea why this HTML code could be causing problems? The code is created for each object in an array, and I have an update every x seconds that clears the array and adds new objects to it. So the HTML elements get removed and recreated every now and then.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "but as you can see, there's no text". The white space you have in your template between the `<p>` and `<img>` tags will be created as a text node in the browser. Just wanted to give you an FYI on why you were seeing those text nodes (and many others, which will be there for all of the rest of the white space in your template).

Comment: I see. Any idea why they are not garbage collected? :)